# apache mod_rewrite rule parse or split subdomain to find virtual host entry

Tags: apache, parsing, mod-rewrite, subdomain, virtualhost

I would like to append variables to my subdomain. Can Apache mod_rewrite parse a subdomain to determine which virtual host entry to use?

I need to stay within my wildcard SSL certificate, so I am locked into the following subdomain format:

```
https://subdomain.testing.mydomain.com
```

I want more flexibility for testing the subdomain against versions of my php libraries though. It would be great if I could pass along more information into the subdomain than just its name. For example:

```
https://subdomain-option1-option2.testing.mydomain.com
```

I have written a php script that parses the entire hostname and pulls out $option1 and $option2 from the subdomain. I then use those values to configure which version of my php library to import and run code against. The problem is that I don't want to hard-code a virtual host entry for each possible combination of subdomain and option1 and option2. I just want Apache to recognize the first part of the hyphen-delimited subdomain and use that to look up the virtual host entry and execute the index file in its directory.

I would need the url to remain intact across page requests. The regex in the Apache mod_rewrite rule will need to detect the first subdomain and extract everything up to the first hyphen (if any), and then use that value to find the appropriate virtual host entry. Has anyone done anything like this before, or is this a scenario that Apache mod_rewrite may not be able to handle?

Answer (score 0):

In the regular expression for the **RewriteCond**, you can put parentheses around parts of the **HTTP_HOST** that you want to capture. This will set numeric variables (**%1**,**%2**,**%3**,etc.) that you can then insert into the substitution string of the **RewriteRule**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]*)[\-]+[a-z0-9\-]+[\.]testing[\.]mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/sites/%1$1 [L,QSA]
```